# How can i remap a list based on different conditions in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list of custom objects (Buffer [CustomObject] ) on which I'm applying .map, in order to return a list of (String,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean) only if at least one of the conditions on the element are met. The string is taken inside the custom object. The code is something like this :

```
list.map{ item=>
  val string = item.string
  val boolean1 = true
  val boolean2 = true
  val boolean3 = true

  //-- some code to check the conditions -- //

  if (!boolean1 || !boolean2 || !boolean3)
    (string,boolean1,boolean2,boolean3)
  else
    null
}
```

The issue with this is that the list obviously contains some null values, and I need to remove them later. I also tried to use .collect() but without success, given that the conditions are more than one and must be checked with some code. I know I could use maybe a couple of .filter and .map in order to achieve this but my goal is to do everything in one iteration. Can you help me?
Thanks

Edit: found a "partial" solution, basically you can return an option and using .flatten or a .flatMap that automatically removes None values.

```
list.flatMap{ item=>
  val string = item.string
  val boolean1 = true
  val boolean2 = true
  val boolean3 = true

  //-- some code to check the conditions -- //

  if (!boolean1 || !boolean2 || !boolean3)
    Some (string,boolean1,boolean2,boolean3)
  else
    None
}
```

But it is a kind of "ugly" solution, is there a more "elegant" one?

Comment: Why the solution using `Option` is _"ugly"_ and what would be more _"elegant"_ for you?

Comment: Cause you're creating many "None" items inside the list, and I was hoping for a kind of .collect approach, where if the item doesn't satisfiy the condition, it automatically skips to the next without creating a None object

Comment: `None` is a singleton, so you don't create many of them. - Anyways, you may do a `map` and then a `collect` but that are two iterations, unless you use a lazy collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage that `flatMap` on `List` threats `Options` as collections of at most one element.

```scala
list.flatMap { item=>
  val string = item.string
  val boolean1 = true
  val boolean2 = true
  val boolean3 = true

  Option.when((!boolean1 || !boolean2 || !boolean3)) {
    (string,boolean1,boolean2,boolean3)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is Option.when  a member of scala.Option?

Comment: @AlbertoPuritano yes: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option$.html

Comment: For some reason my IDE doesn't recognize it, maybe I'm using an older version of Scala

Comment: @AlbertoPuritano probably,bit may have been added in `2.13` and given you mentioned **Spark** on your question you are probably on `2.11`